# The spreading of the wave function and Causality violation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, causality, time-evolution

In Hegerfeldt, 1998 paper "Instantaneous Spreading and Einstein Causality in
Quantum Theory" he states that,

> "In nonrelativistic quantum mechanics the immediate spreading of wave functions over all space is a well known phenomenon".

In which he states that it is of no concern. What does he mean by the spreading of the wave function? and if so isn't this a causality violation in the non-relativistic QM.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147553/226902 (non-hyperbolic PDE like the heat equation or Sch. Equation often allow for the spreading of signals with infinite speed). See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213954/226902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In non relativistic QM the solutions of the (free) Schroedinger equation have the same properties as the solutions of the heat equation: suppose that at time $t=0$ the solution (wavefuncion) $\psi(t=0, \vec{x})$ vanishes outside a spatial **bounded** region. For every arbitrarily large  $R>0$ and every arbitrarily small time $t>0$, there are points  $\vec{x}$ with $||\vec{x}|| >R$ such that $\psi(t,\vec{x}) \neq 0$.

In principle this is not a problem since, in non-relativistic physics, there is no finite bound for propagation  velocities.